# What is the origin of "fine" meaning a legal penalty?

Tags: etymology, legalese

What is the origin of the word *fine* meaning a legal penalty involving the payment of a sum of money?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[fine](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=fine) -

> c.1200, "termination," from Old French fin "end, limit, boundary; death; fee, payment, finance, money" (10c.), from Medieval Latin finis "a payment in settlement, fine or tax," from Latin finis "end"

Comment: Isn't this general reference?

Comment: Yes, but every time I make a comment with "GR" someone posts the link I post and gets rep for it. So now I do both